# Calling metadata in a single.php file

Tags: post-meta

In the following code:`<?php echo "codice alloggio: ",get_the_ID(), colormag_entry_meta(); ?>` 
How could I add metadata values after get_the-ID? In particular I'd like to call the value of the meta key"function_number", you can see this meta also in this code:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, "function_number", $number );
```

In my functions.php file

Comment: Do you mean how do you read the value you set with `update_post_meta( $post_id, "function_number", $number );` ? That's `get_post_meta( $post_id, "function_number" )`. Else I'm not sure what you're asking. What is colormag_entry_meta() ? Is that from a plugin, or your theme?

Comment: And just to check what you're doing with the update_post_meta: as a rule you shouldn't be making database changes like that from templates. You don't want to be writing to your database on page loads if possible, from a database load point of view and also because it'll make the site harder to cache. Is this details of accommodation a customer has just booked?

Comment: @Rup update_post_meta is in the functions.php file, I wrote it just to make understand the function name, but unluckily get_post_meta( $post_id, "function_number" ) is not working :( It's a detail of all accomodations and it should appear near the post ID (accomodation code) and other meta data like number of guests and number of bedrooms

Comment: @Rup Colormag is my main theme, but I use a child theme